# Exporting data from android app to the consumer's google sheet

Tags: android, excel, flutter, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have an app that lets people store data in an orderly manner inside the app.
It displays the data as a table and uses SQLite to store the data in the device.

Though this was enough for some users, many of them asked for a feature that would let the app export the app's data to their own private google sheet. The data is not synced with any other server and resides on the app only.

The problem I am facing is almost all of the guides on the internet show how to sync with your database to which you have access, for example, the name of the sheet, etc.
While this can be used for analytics purposes, this is not what I need.

The data is also highly confidential, so I cannot first copy to my sheet and then transfer it to their sheet(Even if such a feature exists)

Please provide me with detailed steps on how to get access write access to private sheets without breaking the confidentiality of the data itself(directly from the app to the sheet).

P.s: I am using the Flutter framework, and is an android only app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most safest/secure way is to export  the database data as [csv](/questions/tagged/csv). It is easily imported as Google sheets by users of your app. This avoids

- asking users permission to access their Google drive
- oauth or any authorization procedures
- The format is also  widely accepted by a variety of spreadsheet softwares like [excel](/questions/tagged/excel).

---

> How to get access write access to private sheets without breaking the confidentiality of the data itself(directly from the app to the sheet).

This can be attempted using [service-accounts](/questions/tagged/service-accounts)[<sup>docs</sup>](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts). However, as a service account owner, You will have access to the data. In addition, You have to take care of entire authorization flow and data security.

Comment: I guess I just have to go with the CSV method. Thanks for the answer. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: How can I programmatically open a CSV file with google sheet app ?

Comment: Use apps script with `DriveApp` or `Utilties.parseCsv()` or [tag:google-sheets-api] @GkMohammadEmon

Answer (score 0):

### If you don't want to directly access the user data, deploy a standalone Apps Script as a Web App

To do so, you will need at least a `doGet(e)` or `doPost(e)` method as said in the [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

You can access your parameters by following [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters).

Here's an example of how you can treat your data in your Web App:

```
function doPost(e) {
  /*
   *  jsonData = {
   *   data: [
   *     ['column1', 'column2', 'column3'],
   *     ['row1c1', 'row1c2', 'row1c3'],
   *     ['row2c1', 'row2c2', 'row2c3'],
   *     ['row3c1', 'row3c2', 'row3c3']
   *   ]
   * }
   */
  const jsonData = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  
  var exportDataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(`Export-${new Date()}`);
  var sheet = exportDataSheet.getActiveSheet();

  var rangeData = sheet.getRange(1, 1, jsonData.data.length, jsonData.data[0].length);
  rangeData.setValues(jsonData.data);
}
```

Once you have created your **Standalone Apps Script** method `doGet(e)` or `doPost(e)` you need to [deploy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app) your script as a web app and then access the endpoint given after the deployment (https://script.google.com/a/google.com/macros/s/ID/exec) via HTTP POST request.

The Spreadsheet created will be created by the user who accesed the endpoint if you configured it.

Comment: Will this create a private spreadsheet in the user's google drive?